# Vim double-indents python files

Tags: python, vim

I get the following behavior. Given this `settings.py` snippet, hitting 'o' from line 33

```
31# Application definition
32 
33 INSTALLED_APPS = [
34     'rest_framework',
```

I get this

```
31# Application definition
32 
33 INSTALLED_APPS = [
34         |<-cursor is here, two indents, 8 spaces
35     'rest_framework',
```

What I really want would be one indent, or a total of 4 spaces, in line with the rest of the list. What gives? I'm using the following .vimrc which I mostly cribbed from [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/).

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" Add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle used Bundle instead of Plugin)

" Themes
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

if has('gui_running')
  set background=dark
  colorscheme solarized
else
  colorscheme zenburn
endif

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 textwidth=79 expandtab autoindent fileformat=unix

set encoding=utf-8
set nu
let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because of default vim indentation plugin for Python. It inserts 2 `shiftwidth` on the first line below `[`.

You can see code which causes this behaviour here: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/0b9e4d1224522791c0dbbd45742cbd688be823f3/runtime/indent/python.vim#L74

I would recommend you to install [`vim-python-pep8-indent`](https://github.com/hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent) plugin which does indentation inside parenthesis exactly as you need.

Answer (score 8):

According to the code of [`python.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/0b9e4d1224522791c0dbbd45742cbd688be823f3/runtime/indent/python.vim#L74) provided by @Alik, you can notice that it inserts 2 `shiftwidth` **by default**.

```
return indent(plnum) + (exists("g:pyindent_open_paren") ? eval(g:pyindent_open_paren) : (shiftwidth() * 2))
```

But you can change this using the `g:pyindent_open_paren` variable.

For instance:

```
let g:pyindent_open_paren=shiftwidth()
```

Or

```
let g:pyindent_open_paren=4
```

Comment: Note that the dictionary values can be set to an expression, so that you can change the value of 'shiftwidth' later: `let g:python_indent.open_paren = 'shiftwidth()'` (more explanation and options available in `:h ft-python-indent`)